# Learning the price of the last closed position

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to learn the closing price of the last closed position in Pine Script 5 and assign it to a variable, but I haven't been able to figure out how to achieve this.

Before applying long conditions, I want it to wait for the price to decrease by 0.2% from the last closed position, and similarly, before applying short conditions, I want it to wait for the price to increase by 0.2% from the last closed position.

Comment: Please read [ask] and learn how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in variable `strategy.closedtrades.exit_price()`.

> Returns the price of the closed trade's exit.

```
last_close_price = strategy.closedtrades.exit_price(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
```

Comment: The OP has shown no effort at all: no code, no errors... nothing. Just a requirement.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I just answered his initial question. It is difficult to do what he wants to do if he doesn't know that there is a built-in function for it.